# Is there a way to call a function right after 'resumelayouts' event processing finishes?

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

I change width for dozens gridpanel columns. I want to show a mask while it is performing.

```
grid.setLoading(true);
Ext.suspendLayouts();
// columns -- grid columns
columns.forEach(function (column) {
    column.setWidth(...);
}, this);
// fires 'resumelayouts' event and immediately returns.
Ext.resumeLayouts();
// performs before everything updates its layout, which takes 3-4 seconds.
grid.setLoading(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you end up tying up the current "thread" so the browser doesn't get a chance to repaint. You could do something like this:

```
grid.setLoading(true);
setTimeout(function() {
    Ext.suspendLayouts();
    columns.forEach(function (column) {
        column.setWidth(...);
    }, this);
    Ext.resumeLayouts();
    grid.setLoading(false);
}, 1);
```

The above relinquishes control from the current "thread" and allows the repaint before it begins the layout operation.

Comment: I tried this. It does not work, because (as I mentioned in the comment) resumeLayouts() just fire the event and returns control. Then event handlers do all job asynchronously (I guess). At the same time the page keeps old widths.

Comment: If you want it to flush, then you need to call `Ext.resumeLayouts(true);`.